# Menu links not working in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If I run the code without bootstraps container and rows etc.. it does work.
But if i run the code like this snippet inside container etc. the ahref's are not working!
Unless i remove the z-index, but i want the menu to look like it is now.
This have been bugging me for a couple of hours now, and i need someone with a different way of "look" at this problem.

```css
.row.content {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid #600d17;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav {
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #550d15;
}

header {
  padding: 30px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #600d17;
}

footer {
  padding: 30px;
  border-top: 3px solid #600d17;
}

#somename {
  border: 1px solid #600d17;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #600d17;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  /* If i delete this, everything works... */
}

#somename a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#topheader {
  border: 1px solid #460a11;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #460a11;
  padding: 10px 4px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>sometitle</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="container-fluid">
    Header text
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-xs-3 sidenav">
        <div id="topheader">
          <p>Menu</p>
          <div id="somename">
            <a href="#">somelink</a>
            <a href="#">somelink</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 main">
        <section>
          <h1>Title content</h1>
          <p>
            Some story...
          </p>
        </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-3 sidenav">
        right menu
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p>Footer Text</p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's your `z-index` issue. Why is it `-1`?

Comment: it seems like the button where your href is sinking and you thought its not working but you just can't click it.

Comment: I need the z-index because i need the top part to override. Without bootstrap it does work with the z-index... Thats the whole problem im having, please help xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your id `somenname` is inside of your outer id `topHeader`.

You simply need to use `z-index` on 2 separate `div` in your case

> Separate `topheader` and `somename`

Now overlap `topheader` on `somename` by following code:

```
#topheader{
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
}
#somename{
    z-index:1;
}
```

```css
.row.content {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid #600d17;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav {
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #550d15;
}

header {
  padding: 30px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #600d17;
}

footer {
  padding: 30px;
  border-top: 3px solid #600d17;
}

#somename {
  border: 1px solid #600d17;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #600d17;
  position: relative;
  margin: -10px 5px 0px 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* If i delete this, everything works... */
}

#somename a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#topheader {
  border: 1px solid #460a11;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #460a11;
  padding: 10px 4px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>sometitle</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="container-fluid">
    Header text
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-xs-3 sidenav">
        <div id="topheader">
          <p>Menu</p>
        </div>
        <div id="somename">
          <a href="#">somelink</a>
          <a href="#">somelink</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 main">
        <section>
          <h1>Title content</h1>
          <p>
            Some story...
          </p>
        </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-3 sidenav">
        right menu
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p>Footer Text</p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wauw, almost though xD i need the top part to exceed the width. If i change it to width: 110% the 10% goes to the right i need it to be 50/50 like my example

Comment: `margin:-10px 5px 0px 5px;` by adding this to `#somename`. Please check edit.

Comment: F***, So basically i missed one z-index and some margin xD

Comment: Thanks though, that was my problem, i learned something today ;)

Comment: Yup, that's easy to miss when you start using libraries like bootstrap and few others.

Comment: Click the tick mark next to my answer to mark it correct please.

Comment: Thanks for your time 0_-